# Running or debugging Ruby code in Visual Studio Code gives me no output or message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code

This is on my work computer. I just joined the company. I'm trying to run ruby, hopefully line-by-line as well, in Visual Studio Code. I installed the ruby extension, but when I try to run or debug the code, and select the Ruby environment, I don't get any output in the "OUTPUT" and "DEBUG CONSOLE" tabs. I don't know why this is happening. Do I not actually have Ruby installed or something? Thank you.

[Here is a screenshot collage of my issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3Nn9.png)

Comment: I can't even get it to throw errors.

Comment: I may not have had ruby installed, but now I do and it still doesn't work. The ruby VS Code extension build is failing, along with circleci.